# how to set time interval of 1.5 hours?

Tags: java

In the following code the time interval is of 1 hour but I want a time interval of 1.5 hour. For example 8:30-10:00. What am I doing wrong? or is there any Java library which can help me set my desired time interval of 1.5 hour?

```
private static void createLectureTime()
{
    for (int i=8; i<16; i++)
    {           
        lectureTimings.add(i+":30"+" TO "+(i+1)+":00");             
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Date and Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) or [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of fiddling with ints and strings.

Comment: If you only want to add 8 timings do it without a for loop (call luctureTimings.add() eight times). Its easier than calculating the correct times in a for-loop.

Comment: This code looks as though its iterates over the hours 8-16...so it would be...8.30 - 9.30 - 10.30....to 16:30 and then prints out whatever hour it is currently + 1, basically whatever "half hour TO the next full hour" because the last part of the string ends in ":00" so because it is :30 - :00 you are only incrementing effectively by 1 half hour at a time,to increment a whole hour you would have to make the end :30 as well and for 1.5 hour increments you would have to leave it as it is but increment the (i+2) instead of 1....but maybe use Date or @Mein Name's suggestion as they seem simpler..

Comment: for (int i=8; i<16;i++)
 { 
lectureTimings.add(i+":30"+" TO "+(i+2)+":00");
 i=i+2;
 lectureTimings.add(i+":00"+" TO "+(i+1)+":30");
 } 
} 
what about this ?
its working thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar class to solve this problem.Here is the code.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(startTime);
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 90);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: for (int i=8; i<16;i++)
     {           
         lectureTimings.add(i+":30"+" TO "+(i+2)+":00");             
    
     i=i+2;
     lectureTimings.add(i+":00"+" TO "+(i+1)+":30"); 
     }
 
  }
its also working
thankss